# Помогите исправить ошибку: сумма делителей числа

Tags: c++

Имеется код программы, который находит сумму делителей числа. Правда он не мой и написан лично для меня не понятно. Пыталась расписать код (закомментирован), но ничего не вышло. Вычисляет только для нечетных чисел и то не всегда правильно. Подскажите где я ошиблась.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

//int sd(int n, int d=1)
//{     
//  if (d <= n)
//  {
//      if(n % d == 0)
//          return d + sd(n, d + 1);
//      else
//          return sd(n, d + 1);
//  }
//}

int sd(int n, int d=1)
{
    return d <= n ? (n % d == 0? d + sd(n, d + 1) : sd(n, d + 1)) : 0;
}

int main() 
{ 
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
    int n; 
    cout<<"Дано натуральное число найти сумму его делителей через рекурсию \n"<<endl;
    cout << "Введите натуральлное число, n = "; cin >> n;
    cout <<"Сумма делителей натурального числа = "<<sd(n)<<endl; 
    system ("pause");
    return 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int sd(int n, int d=1)
{
    return d <= n ? (n % d == 0? d + sd(n, d + 1) : sd(n, d + 1)) : 0;
}
```

**==>**

```
int sd(int n, int d=1)
{
    if(d <= n)  //Если делитель меньше нужного числа, то идем дальше
    {
        if( n % d == 0) //если число n делится на d без остатка
        {
            return d + sd(n, d+1); //возвращаем сумму этого делителя + все суммы остальных делителей, которые делятся без остатка.
        }
        else 
        {
           return sd(n, d+1); //возвращаем суммы остальных делителей, которые делятся без остатка
        }
    } 
    else 
    {
        return 0; //на этой итерации нет делителей для числа
    }
}
```

Comment: ps. интересно, если топик стартеры не будут прикидываться девушками, то им совсем никто не ответит?

Comment: @Deadkenny: Угу. Хоть бы фото прикладывали в профиль.

Comment: Спасибо большое. Теперь вижу свою ошибку

Answer (score 2):

О, а хороший код. Написан человеком, который слыхал о рекурсии (правда, не о хвостовой).

Смотрите. Функция `sd` у вас в двух экземплярах. Они равнозначны, просто первый вариант попроще расписан. Давайте его и рассмотрим.

Итак, как у нас определяется сумма делителей? Определим функцию `sd(n, d)`: сумма делителей числа `n`, которые *больше или равны* `d`. Почему так? Потому что эту функцию легко определить рекурсивно, и она даёт нам искомый результат, если положить `d = 1`.

Рекуррентное соотношение такое:

1. Если `n` делится на `d`, то `d` — один из делителей, и `sd(n, d)` есть `d` плюс остальные делители (то есть, для больших `d`). Итак, для этого случая `sd(n, d) = d + sd(n, d + 1)`.
2. Если не делится, то очевидно `sd(n, d) = sd(n, d + 1)`
3. Если `d > n`, `sd(n, d) = 0`, и дальше можно не считать.

Соответственно этому код:

```
int sd(int n, int d=1)
{     
    if (d <= n) // случай 3?
    {
        // нет. тогда может случай 1?
        if(n % d == 0)
            return d + sd(n, d + 1); // да!
        else
            return sd(n, d + 1); // нет, случай 2.
    }
    // тут потеряно else return 0; для полного разбора случая 3
    // в незакомментированной функции этот случай есть
}
```

С вас что-то вкусное для того, кто написал код.

---

Да, и код правильный.